# Video Editing - video strips go black after adding images

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I had a few .mov video files in channel 1, and it rendered fine, but then I tried to add an mp4, and I got an error (xyz.mp4 could not be loaded), so I decided to add some .jpg images instead.

The images rendered fine, but when they weren't on screen, it would render as black. Even when I removed the images, it would render as black.

I tried duplicating one of the strips from the first channel and putting it into the second channel (hoping is was just an issue with the channels), and it still had that issue.

But when I added a new .mov, it would render that one fine, but it wouldn't fix the other strips.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a .blend file? I don't think your description or image will be enough to really understand where the issue is coming from, or if this is a bug with Blender (in which case, this doesn't belong on this site)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai3cn1u81wpmm9r/Wales_OverviewOfTheTrip.blend2?dl=0

Comment: Can you download it ?

Comment: You didn't pack the files so I can't see your issue. If you go to file->external data->pack all, it should pack your videos into the file so that we can see them when you share your .blend. Also, could you (or me with your permission, add the .blend using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? Thanks

Comment: There is several files there, each more than 1GB in size this is going to be one big file is there a way to avaoid uploading all of them  ?

Comment: okay, probably not a good idea to do that then. Can you simplify it down to something smaller that still shows the issue?

Comment: I cannot move to chat as I have 1 point only. This really annoys me, I will probably use adobe. It blows my mind why a software so powerfull would not allow the user combine MOV files with mp4 files and JPG files by default. I wasted entire day trying to make a 3 min movie.

Comment: Okay. We're here to help you out if you decide to give Blender another shot.

Comment: Make sure to set your Blend Mode correctly for each clip. Mostly you want to have Replace/Alpha Over, not Cross.